# Spring search function returning full list when nothing is searched

Tags: java, sql, spring, jsp

In my spring application, I have added a search function where the user can search the database for a name, it works except when I'm searching for names or similar names, but for when the I enter nothing and search, it should return nothing but returns the full list of names.

I set the list to return null if it is null, what is the flaw in my logic?

from testing and using the findbyname SQL I think it is a flaw in my SQL state

the controller method used is

```
@RequestMapping("search")
public ModelAndView SearchBeers(@RequestParam("searchTerm") String searchTerm) {

    return new ModelAndView("/Searchbeers", "beerList", service.Search(searchTerm));

}
```

service method called is

```
 public List<Beers> Search(String searchTerm) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    List<Beers> list = null;

    try {
        list = em.createNamedQuery("Beers.findByLikeName", Beers.class)
                .setParameter("name", searchTerm)
                .getResultList();
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            list = null;
        }

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

and the SQL statement used is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Beers.findByLikeName", query = "SELECT b FROM Beers b WHERE b.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:name,'%')")
```

the JSP for when displaying the list is

```
   <c:forEach items="${beerList}" var="beer"> 
            <tr>
                <td>${beer.id}</td>
                <td>${beer.name}</td>
                <td>${beer.abv}</td>


                <td>
                    <form action="/Assignment3/beer/viewBeer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${beer.id}"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.viewDetails"/>"/>
                    </form>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to solve that, but the problem is, when the String is empty your query is:

```
SELECT b from Beers b Where b.name LIKE '%%'
```

So, you need do antoher flag, when have an empty String, because ... `LIKE '%%'` find every name.

PD: Not a good practice return a null, is better a empty list.